# How to replace displayed output from SQL server with PHP

Tags: php, sql

Is there a way to automatically replace an echoed word or phrase in PHP from table row

in data base I have codes I just want auto display it as a name not code in php

```html
echo '
    <tr>
    
    <td>'.$row['MobName'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['CharName'].'</td>
    <td>'.$row['time'].'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
echo '</table>';
```

$row['MobName'] display the code I want auto replace this code with a specific name.
by the way its multiple codes.
how I can do it ?

Comment: When you say "$row['MobName'] display the code" do you mean that you are seeing the actual PHP code displayed in your browser?  Or do you mean that you are seeing some "code" (like an abbreviation or something) that _represents_ a "name", but is still the correct and actual text pulled from your db?

Comment: the code call by the query from the database so its display on the php

Comment: look this is the output I got http://prntscr.com/r7kmfh
 simply I want auto replace the mob name with a pacific name

Comment: So then just remove the PHP code and replace it with static text.

Comment: What do you mean by "pacific name"?

Comment: you did not get me yet this table change every moment the info inside it called by a query from the db so static text will not help.

Comment: @matto.rebeschi I mean specific name example 'MOB_OA_URUCHI' change to 'Uruchi'

Comment: @MohamedTevez  You said "replace this code with a specific name".  If that's not what you actually want, then you need to be more clear about what you want.  Saying that you want "a specific name" would _generally_ mean that you want static text.  Otherwise, it wouldn't be _specific_.  If the name is not static, you need to tell us how you are getting the name.

Comment: @PatrickQ well to be more clear I want to change this code when displayed MOB_KK_ISYUTARU with any name I want , Sorry If I cant explain

Comment: But you need to have some sort of _logic_ that defines the relationship between the "code" and the "name".  Should _all_ codes be replaced with a name or only some?  Do you have some sort of mapping list?  Why isn't the name just stored in the database like the "code" is?

Comment: yes all codes should replace with names , and the names not stored in the db cuz the db record the codes from game server which have only codes not name so that I want auto replace it on the website with names

Comment: With _what_ names though?  The names need to come from _somewhere_.  Your code can't just magically know that "MOB_KK_ISYUTARU" means something else.  You have to _tell_ it.  If you don't have some sort of mapping defined, or some sort of translation logic (take the last 5 characters of the code, and then lowercase them, for example), then this just isn't something that can be done.

Comment: yes this what I mean how to make a list in php with str_replace for example make it like that http://prntscr.com/r7l7wb

Comment: Then... do a str_replace? If you already know that [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is the solution to your problem, what is the question?

Comment: @MohamedTevez  So you _do_ have a mapping array.  I asked you about this multiple times.  You just need to use the code as the index of the array.  Something like `echo $list[$row['MobName']];`

Comment: @matteo.rebeschi actually I don't know how to make it if you give me an example I can try it will be a great solution from you :)

Comment: there is no any mapping array or list exist in the php I just want to know how to make such thing and make it work.

Comment: Okay, I'm done here.  You just _showed_ the mapping array in the picture.  Now you say it doesn't exist.  Hire a freelancer to do your project for you.

Comment: the screen what i showed you was an example from many examples I try it and didn't work with me , any way thank you for your support and interest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, from the pic in the comment:

```
<td>'.str_replace ('MOB_CH_TIGERWOMAN', 'Tiger Girl', $row['MobName']) .'</td>
```

You can also do them all in one go as str_replace supports arrays as arguments:

```
<td>'.str_replace (['MOB_CH_TIGERWOMAN', 'MOB_OA_URUCHI'], ['Tiger Girl', 'Uruchi'], $row['MobName']) .'</td>
```

Every element from the first array will be replaced by the corresponding element of the second array.

Comment: Thank you very much I got it now :)